# Meaning of "would"

Tags: will-would, would-rather

What is the meaning of "would" in the following sentence:

> He would sometimes relive the battle in his dreams.

Is it about what may happen in the future or about something that used to happen in the past?

It seems meanings 12 and 13 in the following dictionary allow both meanings:
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would

Comment: It means repeated habitual action in the past.

Comment: Need more context. Jack O's comment is probably correct. But if it was something like a description of the trauma that will result from a battle about to happen, it might be an indication of a future event.

Comment: @Dan there's no context. It is an example in a dictionary.